# Symfony embedded form collection not persisting

Tags: php, symfony, collections, controller, doctrine

I'm trying to build a form that can contain multiple questions (Age, sex, ...), and for that I need to add fields dynamically, I followed [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) guide, and the button to add fields works great.

[Added fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECQ73.png)

But then, when I submit my form, it only contains the values of the form minus the added fields via JS
[`var_dump()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6kyo.png), where it should contain `question[0], [1]...`

Output of `var_dump()`:

```
array(1) { ["recruitment_form"]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(6) "ezrzer" ["description"]=> string(15) "
zzrrez

" ["submit"]=> string(0) "" ["_token"]=> string(131) "d3e9191f742255bb23bf5d69b628d.u4Ko0rH_5plSnfypsRTxNVL3" 
} }
```

Controller:

```
 #[Route('/admin/server/form/create', name: 'create_form')]
    public function admin_create_form(Request $request, ManagerRegistry $doctrine): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(RecrutementFormType::class);
        
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() AND $form->isValid()) {
            $recrutementForm = $form->getData();
            foreach($form->get('questions') as $q) {
                $question = new FormInput($q);
                $doctrine->getManager()->persist($question);
                $recrutementForm->addQuestion($question);
            }
            $doctrine->getManager()->persist($recrutementForm);
            $doctrine->getManager()->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('view_server', ['id' => $recrutementForm->getId()]);
        }
        
        return $this->render('recrutement_form/admin/form.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

RecrutementFormType:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\RecrutementForm;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ButtonType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class RecrutementFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Nom du formulaire',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'Description',
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'ckeditor form-control'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('questions', CollectionType::class, [
                'label' => 'Questions',
                'entry_type' => QuestionFormType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Valider',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success'
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => RecrutementForm::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

QuestionFormType:

```
<?php
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use App\Entity\FormInput;

class QuestionFormType extends AbstractType
{
    
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Nom interne de la question', 
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-control'
            ]
        ])
        ->add('title', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Titre de la question',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-control'
            ]
        ])
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class, [
            'label' => 'Description',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'ckeditor form-control'
            ]
        ])
        ->add('type', InputType::class, [
            'label' => 'Type de champ',
        ])
        ;
    }
    
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => FormInput::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Twig Template:

```
{% extends 'form.html.twig' %}
{% block formblock %}
<div class="container">
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    
        {% if form_errors(form) is not empty %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{ form_errors(form) }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col lg-12">
                {{ form_row(form.name) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                {{ form_row(form.description) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <ul class="questions" data-index="{{ form.questions|length > 0 ? form.questions|last.vars.name + 1 : 0 }}" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.questions.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
                    {% for q in form.questions %}
                        {{ form_row(q) }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <button type="button" class="add_item_link" data-collection-holder-class="questions">Add a tag</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
         <div class="row>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                {{ form_row(form.submit) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
<script>  
const addFormToCollection = (e) => {
  const collectionHolder = document.querySelector('.' + e.currentTarget.dataset.collectionHolderClass);

  const item = document.createElement('li');

  item.innerHTML = collectionHolder
    .dataset
    .prototype
    .replace(
      /__name__/g,
      collectionHolder.dataset.index
    );

  collectionHolder.appendChild(item);

  collectionHolder.dataset.index++;
};
document
  .querySelectorAll('.add_item_link')
  .forEach(btn => {
      btn.addEventListener("click", addFormToCollection)
  });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

I'm using Symfony 6 and PHP 8

Final HTML code when the template is rendered: https://pastebin.com/LWUU1pKv (CKEditor code included, sry)

I guess the fact that the "questions" ul element is outside the form isn't great but can't figure out how to move it as it should already be inside

Comment: It is not intended, it should return a RecrutementForm entity

Comment: Yes, the `</form>` closing tag is breaking the form submission of the questions, since it is what contains the `$_POST['recrutement_form']['questions'][]` values that are processed by `$form->handleRequest($request)`. Additionally preventing the ability to submit the form using the submit button. It looks like CKEditor or other element(s) is breaking the HTML and the browser is interpreting the DOM accordingly. In your browser View Page Source to see how the HTML is output from Twig prior to ECMAScript being executed or trying disabling CKEditor to see how the HTML is rendered afterwards.